# Kafka MM2 Offset Translation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I'm using the Confluent Platform Community Edition (7.4) as a new cluster and I wish to replicate data from my old 2.3 Apache Kafka cluster.

I setup Kafka Connect on the new side and tried to setup MM2 to replicate data. I managed to transfer data, but offset translation is not occuring. These are my configs that I push into Kafka Connect API:

**mm2-source-connector**

```
{
  "name": "mm2-source-connector",
  "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
  "clusters": "my-source,my-target",
  "source.cluster.alias": "my-source",
  "target.cluster.alias": "my-target",
  "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "topics": ".*",
  "tasks.max": "4",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
  "replication.factor": "3",
  "offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor": "3",
  "sync.topic.acls.interval.seconds": "20",
  "sync.topic.configs.interval.seconds": "20",
  "refresh.topics.interval.seconds": "20",
  "refresh.groups.interval.seconds": "20",
  "consumer.group.id": "mm2-mirror-source-consumer-group",
  "source.cluster.security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT",
  "target.cluster.security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT",
  "replication.policy.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy",
  "groups": ".*"
}
```

**mm2-checkpoint-connector**

```
{
  "name": "mm2-checkpoint-connector",
  "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector",
  "clusters": "my-source,my-target",
  "source.cluster.alias": "my-source",
  "target.cluster.alias": "my-target",
  "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "tasks.max": "4",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
  "replication.factor": "3",
  "checkpoints.topic.replication.factor": "3",
  "emit.checkpoints.interval.seconds": "20",
  "source.cluster.security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT",
  "target.cluster.security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT",
  "refresh.groups.interval.seconds": "30",
  "refresh.topics.interval.seconds": "30",
  "sync.group.offsets.enabled": "true",
  "emit.checkpoints.enabled": "true",
  "replication.policy.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy",
  "sync.group.offsets.interval.seconds": "30",
  "topics": ".*",
  "groups": ".*"
}
```

I am able to see the consumer groups and the messages being transferred, but offset translation isn't happening even though I followed this instructions:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-545%3A+support+automated+consumer+offset+sync+across+clusters+in+MM+2.0

Which say that these two options sync.group.offsets.enabled and emit.checkpoints.enabled should be set on the checkpoint connector.

Is this a constraint so that Confluent Replicator would be used? I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Don't replicate. Do a rolling restart/upgrade https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/post-deployment.html#rolling-restart

Comment: I need to replicate. I need separate clusters. I do not want to upgrade my cluster.

Comment: I see. The post made it seem like you were just upgrading in place... Look at the JIRA linked in the KIP. This feature was only added in Kafka 2.7.0

Comment: I tried the same setup with 2.7.0...didn't work. Not sure what could be wrong. I thought it might be due to Kafka versions, but 2.7.0 brand cluster to Confluent CE 7.4 didn't work as well.